# Configuring Boomi JMS connector to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, activemq-artemis, boomi

I've been using a JMS connector in Boomi to connect with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14, but using the client library activemq-all-5.15.11.jar and factory `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`  This works, except I'm having issues with the connections creating numerous `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.MessageReferenceImpl` objects in the heap, which aren't associated with the actual messages, but rather the `ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue`.

So I'm trying to setup a Boomi JMS connector using the ActiveMQ Artemis 2.14 client. I have the following libraries imported into the Atom:

- activemq-core-5.4.1.jar
- artemis-core-client-2.14.0.jar
- artemis-jms-client-2.14.0.jar
- artemis-jms-client-all-2.14.0.jar
- fscontext-4.6-b01.jar
- geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar

Then I created a Custom Library, set it to Connector JMS, and added the above libraries and deployed to the Atom. In the connector I specified ActiveMQ, and the ConectionFactory `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`

This gives me a java dump, complaining that "Unable to create initial context" and "Invalid broker URL"
My URL is a little fancy, but it works for the other ActiveMQ JMS connector.

```
failover:(tcp://[host]:61616,tcp://[host]:61616)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=2&maxReconnectAttempts=0&maxReconnectDelay=1000
```

So I tried a simple URL, just `tcp://[host]:61616`  This give me a strange error: "Unexpected error executing process: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger"

So does this mean I'm including a library that I don't need, which needs the jboss logger, or do I actually need the jboss logger library?

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of issues to discuss here. I'll take each one in turn.

> ...I'm having issues with the connections creating numerous...objects in the heap, which aren't associated with the actual messages, but rather the `ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue`.

You should be able to resolve this by setting `supportAdvisory=false` on the `acceptor` in `broker.xml` which your clients are using. This is discussed in the [OpenWire chapter in the ActiveMQ Artemis user manual](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/openwire.html#disableenable-advisories).

> I have the following libraries imported into the Atom...

The *only* library you should actually need is `artemis-jms-client-all-2.14.0.jar`. As the name suggests, it contains *all* of the ActiveMQ Artemis client code along with all of the dependencies (e.g. Netty, JMS API classes, JBoss Logging framework, etc.).

> In the connector I specified ActiveMQ, and the ConectionFactory `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`

The class `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` is *not* a JMS `ConnectionFactory` implementation. It is an `InitialContextFactory` implementation for JNDI.

> This gives me a java dump, complaining that "Unable to create initial context" and "Invalid broker URL" My URL is a little fancy, but it works for the other ActiveMQ JMS connector.

The URL you're using is suitable for the OpenWire JMS client used for ActiveMQ 5.x (which you were using previously). However, it is invalid for the core JMS client used for ActiveMQ Artemis (which you are using now). You can use something like this instead:

```
(tcp://[host]:61616,tcp://[host]:61616)?ha=true&initialConnectAttempts=2&reconnectAttempts=0&maxRetryInterval=1000
```